# TypeError: expected token to be a str, received <class 'NoneType'> instead

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I'm wanting to make a simple discord bot. What it does isn't too important other than the fact that I want it to send messages at certain times. The code below is very basic and is not the finished product.

```py
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

intents = discord.Intents().all()
intents.messages = True

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("FAKETOKENBLAHBLAHBLAH")

client = discord.Client(command_prefix=',', intents=discord.Intents().all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Am I doing something wrong? If so, please tell me. I've been stumped for hours now and all I have for reference is this error:

```
TypeError: expected token to be a str, received <class 'NoneType'> instead
```

I understand the other references to modules and line numbers in the traceback, but I just can't understand where it goes wrong, because I didn't write the discord.py module.

I've read so many articles about it, but none of them seem to work. The first article I read told me to leave the parameters of "discord.Client()" completely blank, which gave me this error:

```
TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

That was from the link: https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/#creating-a-discord-account

I don't understand, but I definitely know the biggest issue is about the parameters of discord.Client() and something to do with intents.

I feel I should also attach my .env code:

```
#.env
DISCORD_TOKEN={FAKETOKENBLAHBLAHBLAH}
```

UPDATE:
I fixed this code:

```
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
```

However, now it gives me this exception:

```
[2022-08-22 01:20:03] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\domin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 801, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\domin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 744, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\domin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Projects\Discord Bot Text Game\bot.py", line 19, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\domin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Users\domin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\domin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\domin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\domin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "C:\Users\domin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 580, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "C:\Users\domin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 805, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

How do I go about fixing this? Do I need to generate a new token?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Did you try to **check what happens** when `TOKEN = os.getenv("FAKETOKENBLAHBLAHBLAH")` runs? What is the resulting value of `TOKEN`? Is that what you expect? "and all I have for reference is this error:" This is not true. There will at least be a *traceback* - starting with a line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` This tells you *where* in the program the error occurred.

Comment: "I've read so many articles about it, but none of them seem to work!" It is not useful to tell us this. Instead, tell us: specifically which articles did you read? After reading them, what did you understand from them? Therefore, *what change did you try to make* to the code? *What happened* as a result?

Comment: Please close this question, you found the answer yourself. For the remaining problem, ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

While having the full traceback would be useful in general, the error

> TypeError: expected token to be a str, received <class 'NoneType'> instead

hints that the `token` passed in is `None`, not a string.

Your code

```
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("FAKETOKENBLAHBLAHBLAH")
```

tries to load a .env file (to load variables from it to the process environment) and then accesses the environment variable `FAKETOKENBLAHBLAHBLAH`.

If you don't have `FAKETOKENBLAHBLAHBLAH=...` in your `.env` file or the environment you're running your program in, then `os.getenv()` will return `None`, and `TOKEN` will be None.

It sounds like you might want `os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')` or similar, so you'd use `DISCORD_TOKEN` as an environment variable name.

Comment: I attached my .env file, so I hope that will help clear some things up

Comment: Right. As I suspected, change `FAKETOKENBLAHBLAHBLAH` to `DISCORD_TOKEN` in the `os.getenv()` call.

Comment: That worked, but now there's an issue with passing an improper token, it being static or something. should I get a new token?

Comment: Does the error really say "this token is static or something"? Anyway, sure, try getting a new token and paste it into your envfile.

Comment: @DominicMiller "That worked, but now" Please *ask a new question*. Note well that this is **not a discussion forum** - posts are **not** there to help someone work through a problem until the code works; posts are there to **ask a question** that can be a) clearly understood; b) found by other people using a search engine; c) answered in a way that is useful to everyone who has the same question. Please see [ask] and the [tour] for details.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, I had .env file with same token in other subdirectory. So I deleted it, and kept only the one .env file, and it works.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33006622)

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP 401 Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) is usually raised when request was made with bad credentials. Double check your tokens.